# Large corpus of source code for frequency analysis

Tags: text, code-analysis

Where could I find a large codebase (preferably in C, Java, Ruby, or Python) that I could use? I'm trying to do some analysis on character frequencies and need a large corpus of code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: how about public github repositories?

Comment: public github repositories are already a good advice, but to add some more specific: How about the Linux kernel, Android (Dalvik VM, Core Java Libraries, GUI, ...) or maybe even the whole GNU project?

Comment: openhub.net contain a lot of source code but I don't know if you download it to do analysis

Comment: in addition to github, you can go on sourceforge and do an [advanced search](http://sourceforge.net/directory/language:ruby/) on projects where you can filter on programming languages